# Small red see through worms in houseplants

Tags: identification, pests, pest-control, worms

I bought a plant off of Facebook Marketplace and when I went to give it a watering these small red see through worms were sitting in the watering tray. I’ve watered the plant a few more times since then and I continue to get the small worms after every watering the only difference now is they get smaller in size with each watering. If you have any advice or know what they are that would help thank you!

[image]

Comment: Its a type of earthworm known as a brandling, usually present in compost heaps or where things are rotting, probably present and breeding in the soil in the pot.  Is the plant otherwise healthy, and what is it? Or post a photo

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an ordinary earthworm; I am sure I have some in my pots, I don't find them to be a problem.